# Get property and value from json object in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, android-context

I am writing an android application which interacts with a Rest api which replies back with json object to the applicatoin. I need to get a particular property from that json object (I need to have both key and value of that property). I am using Google volley to access the API.

For Example, Below is a response from the API. I want to extract the property "context" with it's value from the output below, means i want to have the context Object from the output:

```
{
    "input": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "context": {
        "conversation_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "system": {
            "dialog_stack": [
                "Welcome"
            ],
            "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
            "dialog_request_counter": 1,
            "_node_output_map": {
                "Welcome": [
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want/need a database. Volley isn't the problem here, really - your code (mostly) looks fine. You have to do more than Toast in the response.

Comment: Please check the post again, i made it more precise and clear. I think you'll understand it now. What exactly the problem, I am facing. Thanks

Comment: if you know the name of the key then you can check for the value using JsonObject.has("yourKeyHere") (Context in your case) it will return true if there is a mapping exists [see this link for more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String))

Comment: 1) Why did you delete your code? 2) Do you have a Gson object for the `"context"` key? Note: You shouldn't name it `Context` because that is an Android class.